# How to apply different size kernel filters on a single convolutional layer

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am interested in doing a ConvNets in which there are filters with different sizes at the same convolutional layer. How can I make it using Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to split your layer to several parallel conv with different filter sizes. Pad the convolutions according to filter size and then concat the outputs.
Look at GoogLeNet for an example of such configuration.